# Trying to add IJulia via the REPL: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I keep trying to add IJulia in the REPL, and I keep getting this error message:
[image: system error]

I tried installing JSON directly, but the REPL would say "The following packages names could not be resolved".

If it helps, I'm running a Windows 10 laptop with julia 1.0.5

Is there a fix to this? Should I install an earlier version to julia?

Appreciate the time.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Instead post the code as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to add it from the GitHub URL rather than just doing `add IJulia`? Also is there a reason why you are using Julia v1.0, rather than the currrent version 1.4.2?

Comment: @NilsGudat when I enter “add IJulia” the console displays the message “The following package names could not be resolved”. Also, I believe I am using the most up to date version. That was a typo.

Comment: What do you mean it was a typo? You posted a screenshot above that says `(v1.0) pkg>`, indicating that you are using Julia v1.0 (unless you have activated an environment of that name)? While 1.0.4 is the LTS version of Julia, the current release is 1.4.2

Comment: I must’ve misread something. I must have version 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have outdated registries locally.
The registries are `~/.julia/registries`, message like `The following package names could not be resolved` usually suggests that registry are not updated or somehow corrupted.
Delete them (the directory `~/.julia/registries/General`) and then adding packages should cause the General registry to be downloaded, the newest version. Then you should be able to add IJulia without problem.
More people encountered this problem with messed up registry, see https://discourse.julialang.org/t/registry-failed-to-update/17840/10